# Is typedef resolved at compile time in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, typedef

I'm writing a c++ code where I need high performance. But I also want my code to be readable so I'm using `typedef` but I am not sure if this will slow my program down. Also my `typedef` is used in class with `template` so I am not sure if that will change anything or not.
This is the code:

```
template<class T>
class A {
   typedef std::vector<T> v;

};
```

Comment: typedef is resolved totally at compile time. In fact in general C++ programs contain no type information at all.

Comment: C++ programs contain "run time type information" (RTTI) used for catching exceptions and typeid and dynamic_cast, but that's probably not the kind of type information john is referring to (by which I presume is meant reflection and introspection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `typedef` is just something to make an alias. The compiler doesn't care about these internally and it has no impact on the generated code.

The final (non-debug) executable will make no reference to either of these things, it'll all be baked out as machine code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is resolved at compile time. Also there is new better alternative for this `using`.

```
template<class T>
class A {
    // typedef std::vector<T> vector_t;
    using vector_t = std::vector<T>; // new type created

    vector_t   m_array; // now class A has m_array of type std::vector<T>
};
```